# using forEach() to change background color after clicking a button

Tags: javascript, foreach, background-color

I want to change a color everytime I click a button. I use forEach to go through each color. But after I click a button, the color changes to "orange", the last color in the array. Am I missing something in my code?

```js
window.onload = function() {
    const btn = document.querySelector("button");
    btn.addEventListener("click", changeColor); 
}

function changeColor() {
    const colors = ["yellow","green","red","blue","orange"];
    colors.forEach(function(color) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
    });
}
```

```css
body{
    background-color:teal;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 180px;
}

button{
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
    <script src="/js.js"></script>
    <title>1st project</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="button">Click me!</button>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: on each click it sets the background to each color in the array in succession ending in orange.

Comment: so in other words I can't use forEach() method in this case

Comment: Correct, for the effect you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

On each click you are iterating over your `colors` array and setting the background to each color in the array in succession ending in orange.

Instead you need to track the index of the last click and increment it on each click, here using the [remainder operator(%)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) to loop back to 0.

```
let colorIndex=0;
function changeColor() {
    const colors = ["yellow","green","red","blue","orange"];
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex];
    colorIndex = (colorIndex+1)%colors.length;
}
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
    const btn = document.querySelector("button");
    btn.addEventListener("click", changeColor); 
}

let colorIndex=0;
function changeColor() {
    const colors = ["yellow","green","red","blue","orange"];
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex];
    colorIndex = (colorIndex+1)%colors.length;
}
```

```css
body{
    background-color:teal;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 180px;
}

button{
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
    <script src="/js.js"></script>
    <title>1st project</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="button">Click me!</button>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to somehow save the current color then change to the next one.
For this, you could put the current index of the `colors` array in a variable:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    const btn = document.querySelector("button");
    btn.addEventListener("click", changeColor); 
}

let colorIndex = 0;
const colors = ["teal", "yellow","green","red","blue","orange"];

function changeColor() {
    colorIndex++;
    if ( colorIndex >= colors.length) {
        colorIndex = 0; // Circle back to the start
    }
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex];
}
```

```css
body{
    background-color:teal;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 180px;
}

button{
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
    <script src="/js.js"></script>
    <title>1st project</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="button">Click me!</button>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want change color in order, this is a simple method

```
let index = 0;

window.onload = function() {
    const btn = document.querySelector("button");
    btn.addEventListener("click", changeColor);
}

function changeColor() {
    const colors = ["yellow", "green", "red", "blue", "orange"];

    (index != colors.length - 1) ? index++ : index = 0; // Reset if index equals color array length

    document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[index]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to  change the background complete random  then use Math.random() method ( I made it little advanced to set max and min values )

**RANDOM** ( change to  random background color )

```
       window.onload = function() {
      const btn = document.querySelector("button");
      btn.addEventListener("click", changeColor);
    }
    Math.randomNumber = (min, max)=> {
      return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    };
    
    function changeColor() {
      const colors = ["yellow",
        "green",
        "red",
        "blue",
        "orange"];

      // Getting a random num b/w 0 and  colours array length 
      const num = Math.randomNumber(0, colors.length)
     // Chaining the colours 
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[num];
    }
```

**LOOPING** (  if you want to loop in array of colours    )

```
     window.onload = function() {
      const btn = document.querySelector("button");
      btn.addEventListener("click", changeColor);
    }
    // set Default color by changing the value 
    let currentNum = 0;
    function changeColor() {
      const colors = ["yellow",
        "green",
        "red",
        "blue",
        "orange"];
      
      if(currentNum >= colors.length - 1){
         currentNum = 0;
      }else{
        currentNum++
      }
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[currentNum];
    }
```